# Mordell's theorem on rational quadrilaterals

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Mordell proved that for any epsilon and any quadrilateral in the Euclidean plane there is an epsilon-close quadrilateral whose sides and diagonal are rational. Does this break down for five points in the plane? And if so, then what about five points in 3-space?

Comment: Crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362033/generalizations-of-mordells-theorem-on-rational-quadrilaterals. Also, this doesn’t show any attempt to search for an answer via Google. I vote to close.

Comment: I do not vote to close, on the grounds that Peter is an established mathematician who knows how to use search engines. (That said, Peter, the MO etiquette is to avoid crossposting to MSE, as it can lead to duplicated effort)